# How do I disable the Quick edit module?

Tags: theming, 8

I tried uninstalling *Quick edit* via the user interface.

> [image]

I cleared the cache via `drush cr`, but it doesn't work.

> [image]

How can I disable it?

Even `drush en -y quickedit` and `drush pmu quickedit` don't work.

Comment: After uninstalling quick edit module I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want to get rid of the "Edit" pen icon, displayed when you put the mouse over a node.

This is not provided by the "Quick Edit" module. You have to disable "Contextual Links" if you want to get rid of that menu.

Alternatively, if you are using those links for managing blocks for example, you might want to force hiding contextual links on nodes via CSS.

For example:

```
.your-node-selector .contextual {
  display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Rather than hiding the CSS, it is probably best to alter the render array to remove the links entirely.  Think those are part of local tasks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, MPD. I do agree that that's a proper solution. If it's only for administrators, CSS solution is much faster/easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The contextual links are cached in the browser local storage. If you are seeing outdated contextual links, open the developer toolbar and clear out the local storage and session storage. This will repopulate the contextual links from the backend and they will be correct again.